# Firestore app works in debug but signed apk gives error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created complete app with firestore everythings works fine in debug apk but when i create signed apk for publishing it gives me strange error.

While login with signed apk it gives blue lines of

```
 W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [aei]: No setter/field for updated_at found on class com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.j
 W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [aei]: No setter/field for token found on class com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.j
 W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [aei]: No setter/field for image found on class com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.j
 W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [aei]: No setter/field for phone found on class com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.j
```

and red lines with this error.

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                          at com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.ui.login.d$3.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.l.run(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my user model is

```
public class User {

     public Long id;

     public String user_id;

     public String account_type;

     public String image;

     public String password;

     public String gender;

     public String device_id;


     public String name;

     public String address;

     public String type;

     public String country;

     public String age;


    public String occupation;


    public String hobbies;


    public String dreams;


    public String mobile;


    public String email;


    @ServerTimestamp
    public Date  created_at;

    @ServerTimestamp
    public Date  updated_at;





    public long profile_views;


    public double total_followers,total_following,total_images,total_videos,total_stories;


public User(Long id, String user_id, String account_type, String image, String password, String gender, String device_id, String name, String address, String type, String country, String age, String occupation, String hobbies, String dreams, String mobile,
        String email, Date created_at, Date updated_at, long profile_views, double total_followers, double total_following, double total_images, double total_videos, double total_stories) {
    this.id = id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.account_type = account_type;
    this.image = image;
    this.password = password;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.device_id = device_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.type = type;
    this.country = country;
    this.age = age;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.dreams = dreams;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.email = email;
    this.created_at = created_at;
    this.updated_at = updated_at;
    this.profile_views = profile_views;
    this.total_followers = total_followers;
    this.total_following = total_following;
    this.total_images = total_images;
    this.total_videos = total_videos;
    this.total_stories = total_stories;
}



    public User() {
    }


    public User(long l, String currentUserId, String accountType, String currentUserEmail, String currentUserProfilePicUrl,  String currentUserGender, String currentUserDeviceToken, String currentUserName, String currentUserType, long currentUserProfileViews) {
        this.user_id = currentUserId;
        this.account_type = accountType;
        this.image = currentUserProfilePicUrl;

        this.gender = currentUserGender;
        this.device_id = currentUserDeviceToken;
        this.name = currentUserName;
        this.type = currentUserType;
        this.email = currentUserEmail;
        this.profile_views = currentUserProfileViews;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }


    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(String hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    public String getDreams() {
        return dreams;
    }

    public void setDreams(String dreams) {
        this.dreams = dreams;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public Date getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(Date updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }



    public String getUser_id() {
        return this.user_id;
    }



    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }



    public String getAccount_type() {
        return this.account_type;
    }



    public void setAccount_type(String account_type) {
        this.account_type = account_type;
    }



    public String getDevice_id() {
        return this.device_id;
    }



    public void setDevice_id(String device_id) {
        this.device_id = device_id;
    }



    public long getProfile_views() {
        return this.profile_views;
    }



    public void setProfile_views(long profile_views) {
        this.profile_views = profile_views;
    }



    public double getTotal_followers() {
        return this.total_followers;
    }



    public void setTotal_followers(double total_followers) {
        this.total_followers = total_followers;
    }



    public double getTotal_following() {
        return this.total_following;
    }



    public void setTotal_following(double total_following) {
        this.total_following = total_following;
    }



    public double getTotal_images() {
        return this.total_images;
    }



    public void setTotal_images(double total_images) {
        this.total_images = total_images;
    }



    public double getTotal_videos() {
        return this.total_videos;
    }



    public void setTotal_videos(double total_videos) {
        this.total_videos = total_videos;
    }



    public double getTotal_stories() {
        return this.total_stories;
    }



    public void setTotal_stories(double total_stories) {
        this.total_stories = total_stories;
    }
}
```

I have tried lot of answers on stackoverflow by changing naming convention etc but nothing solved my problem.

Comment: might be proguard issue, disable it using minifyEnabled false and generate signed apk. If it works then you need to change in proguard file

Comment: thanks alot @PPD it works with Levi's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your proguard setup doesn't let your model classes be recognized. I'd keep them out of obfuscation with a rule:

```
-keep class com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: can you please explain the cause of this error and how you get that this is related to proguard?

Comment: In order to parse a model class firebase needs the full name of it to use reflection. Proguard makes reflection impossible because it changes the name of your classes to obfuscate your code. So normally, model classes should be kept out of obfuscation because some libs need their full names.

Comment: You can see this is aproguard problem because your class was defnied as com.binrafiq.reborn.mvp.data.db.model.j. J was the name proguard gave to your class to obfuscate it.

Comment: sorry but in my another app i'm getting this error Could not deserialize object. Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead (found in field 'tags')

Comment: can you please help me in detecting that problem is not because of proguard.

Comment: @NoumanCh you also need to add `-keepattributes Signature` to the proguard file: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: @LeviMoreira I had the issue after uploading the app to Google Play. Is it that I have to add `-keep class com.mypackage.name.models.Abc` , `-keep class com.mypackage.name.models.Xyz` , `-keep class com.mypackage.name.models.Pqr` one by one? I have more than 10 models classes. Thanks.

Comment: @NoumanCh Can you check my previous comment and tell me how you accomplished it?

Answer (score 4):

In release mode if enabled the field names and their method names obfuscated by Progaurd lib. You can add annotation to your field names so that they can be recognizable even after obfuscation.

You do not need to disable or skip your class from progaurd. This way your code will be protected.

Like below:

```
@PropertyName("businessId")
private String businessId;
@PropertyName("userId")
private String userId;
```