# a release for internal test in google play not retrieving or uploading any data from/to firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase in my app, in debug apk (using emulator) everything works fine but when I built a release in google play and downloaded the app, data not loaded or showed in the app and I'm not able to add or delete anything in firebase firestore. I've added the release SHA1 fingerprint in firebase as in this link [SHA1 fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630123/flutter-generate-release-sha1-fingerprint) but without downloading google-services.json again, I also find similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587459/firebase-release-apk-not-loading-data)
and tried to set ProGuard configuration as in this question [ProGuard configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android/26274623#26274623)  but I couldn't find proguard-rules.pro file in my app so I just added this to build.gradle(app)

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true  // shrink
        useProguard false   // don't obfuscate

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true  // shrink
        useProguard true    // obfuscate

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a very good troubleshooting process, but I am afraid I will need more information to help you more. Can you please share the documentation or process you are following? I would also download the JSON again. Did you already check the firebase configuration and this file had changed? I would also appreciate it if you could share with us whether your proguard file is in the correct place or something like this. My first thought is that something is failing once the app is in the playstore because it works on the emulator.

Comment: hello, sorry for the late reply, I tried downloading the JSON file again as you mentioned and also I couldn't find the proguard file inside my app... I think it may help mentioning that I was facing a problem in playstore (the app got rejected and released not updated because of data safety and privecy policy but I fixed it and everything went fine) but still my app is not working, not deleting data and retrieving only some data

Comment: also I'm getting this "Error retrieving information from server. [RH-01]" from the play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a whole month I found the answer, it turned out that I didn't add this permission to app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file, so when I edited it everything worked fine

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have dug into this issue (`Error retrieving information from server. [RH-01]`), and apparently this happens when we encounter an "invalid" device ID. I found some troubleshooting you can try, but at the end I think you should contact Play Store Support. In this [page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD8T3pEGyYsIDE/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fplay%2FT3pEGyYsIDE), there are several comments with troubleshooting steps.

Tech Bae says:

> There are five solutions to Fix `Error Retrieving Information from Server RH-01` in Google Play Store.
>
> - Solution 1 – Set Correct Date and Time
> - Solution 2 – Restart your Android Device
> - Solution 3 – Clear Cache and Data of Google Play Store
> - Solution 4 – Re-add your Google Account
> - Solution 5 - Factory Reset your android phone (it will wipe all your data)
>
> To get a detailed tutorial on How To Fix `Error Retrieving Information from Server RH-01` in Google Play Store, visit this webpage - http://www.techbae.com/fix-error-retrieving-information-from-server-rh-01-google-play-store/

And Özkan Korkmaz:

> - Go to: Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Force Stop.
> - Go to: Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Clear Data.
> - Go to: Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Clear Cache.
>
> source: http://wikitechsolutions.com/20570/how-to-fix-error-retrieving-information-from-server-rh-01

If none of these options work, I would try to [Get Help from Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9789798?hl=en&visit_id=637738866020915810-3456762036&rd=2). Then, you can try again with the JSON and the proguard configuration.