# app crash while sign in to firebase using phone Auth in google play's release for internal testing

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I've been facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048948/a-release-for-internal-test-in-google-play-not-retrieving-or-uploading-any-data/70613608#70613608) problem in my app when I released a version for internal testing and finally I found the answer, what I'm facing now is that I'm using google phone number sign in method and everything is working just fine in emulator and in real device but when I download the app from google play for internal testing it crashes every time I try to sign in, I mean when I fill the name - phone number and hit sign in button nothing happens.. there is no code verification, it just closes the app