# Why do firebase related queries not work when I download my app from play store

Tags: android, firebase

I recently published my app on play store, but when I download it and login using correct credentials, the authentication fails. However, for the same package, when I download an APK and directly run the same on a real device, the same credentials work. On the emulator, the firebase related queries work, but on downloading from play store it always fails.

I double checked the signing keys, tried it in different devices but it never works, even though the source code is the same and so are the signing keys. I also double checked the SHA keys on google play console.
As I don't have access to the logs of the android device, I am unable to figure out why the firebase related actions are not working.
In my android manifest file I have mentioned the internet permission.
Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Comment: Please check your proguard rules. 
It seems same problem with that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587459/firebase-release-apk-not-loading-data

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885)?

Comment: yeah so I added the keys, and I also added my proguard rules carefully. Thing is it worked initially in my early versions, but after changing some small features it suddenly stopped working